# character conversion in vim

Tags: linux, vim

I am using vim editor. I learned that

```
shift (and pressing) ~
```

converts upper case letters to lower case and vice versa, and then moves the cursor to the right. Any way to make the cursor move left instead, so pressing `~` repeatedly converts from right to left?

Comment: I don't know of a way of doing that but what I would do is jump to the beginning of the word (using `b` or `F`, etc) and then just do it left to right.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you just said; I think you want to know if there is a way to jump to the beginning of a line? If so just hit `0` (zero) and that will jump to the beginning.

Comment: Do you mean like `g~h` ?

Comment: ernix,If you press in front of line (ESC mode) shift+~(keep press),it will convert the whole line,but I need to convert from end of line to beginning of the line . But your answer converts only one character in right to left.

Comment: Try `g~~` or `guu`.  Keeping certain keys press is not a good practice.  It will pollute your undo history.  You should probably use text-objects instead. see `:help text-objects`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nnoremap <F2> h<S-~>h
```

does something similar. Has a little problem with the last character in a line.

But really, that isn't **that often** used function. Most people just select the word (*viw)* and upper/lowercase it with gU or gu.

Comment: Why are you using `<S-~>`? Simple `~` is enough. And, by the way, there is an `g~` operator (`~` is an operator if `&tildeop` option is enabled). With it mapping should be written as `nnoremap <F2> g~h` which is better as it is repeatable with dot (after executing your mapping dot will act as `~`, not as `h~h`).

Comment: @ZyX - Because I need shift to reach it on my keyboard layout. But good points; edit the answer and put it in if you want.

Comment: @Idigas Vim has no idea what you need to feed it `~`. It won’t treat `<S-~>` differently from `~`, but `<S-~>` construct *looks* like you need to press *two* shifts: one to reach `~` and one for `<S-`.

Comment: @ZyX - I don't use ~ at all. Just patched up the above answer to give the OP a quick way of doing reverse.

Answer (score 0):

As ernix mentioned in the comments, `g~h` or `g~←` should be exactly what you're looking for.

If you're doing it repeatedly, you can use `.` (repeat last change) to keep doing it after you type it out the first time.